# Converting data frame from logical to numeric

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, which after dput is of the following structure:

```
A= structure(list(`12` = logical(0)),
row.names = character(0), class = "data.frame"))
```

I am new to R, but what I wish at the end is to in fact store A as a numeric variable, with value 12. It seems to be an atomic vector? at the moment. For instance, when I type:

```
A <- as.numeric(as.character(A))
```

I am returned a null variable A. When I type instead:

```
A <- lapply(data_list$A, as.numeric)
```

I get again a List of 0. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The dataset doesn't have any rows.  Based on the `dput`, the `12` is the column name and not the value of a column

Comment: Yes, but how can this be fixed? It should be a scalar.  It is clear that the value is supposed to be 12. At the moment, it seems to be stored as an atomic vector

Comment: Yes, the 12 should be the value of the column, named A

Comment: Please check the solution I posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value "12" is the column name and there are 0 rows in the dataset (based on the `dput`).  So, if we want to convert, just use `as.numeric`

```
as.numeric(names(A))
#[1] 12
```

Comment: Amazing. I'll accept it as soon as I am able to. Works like a charm

Comment: Also, Akrun, for one, this is quite easy. Suppose I have two dataframes, A and B. Is there any way to replace both dataframes at the same time? As of now, I would be doing this as A=as.numeric(names(A)) and B=as.numeric(names(B))

Comment: @KwameBrown I would place it in a `list` and use `lapply(list(names(A), names(B)), as.numeric)`

Comment: I actually did List<- c('A', 'B')
for ( i in List){ 
  data_list$ (i)<-as.numeric(names(data_list$(i)))  
}  . However, I get a strange error message.

Comment: @KwameBrown you need `data_list[[i]]` instead of `data_list$`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is likely this snippet:

```
`12` = logical(0)
```

When it says `logical(0)`, it means you have a vector of length 0 (empty). The name of this vector is 12.

When you convert an empty vector into another type, you still get an empty vector (the `NULL` value.

Since your vector is empty, using `lapply` will not work either.